# Load index.html by default in apache2

Tags: apache2, mod-jk, tomcat8, directoryindex

I have set up `apache2` web server and tomcat with `mod_jk` module in between to delegate static content to `apache2`.

I have created `/var/www/example/index.html` and want this to be loaded when entering `www.example.com/`

I can access `www.example.com/index.html` directly but `www.example.com/` loads tomcat default page.

Here is my apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    <Directory /var/www/example>
            DirectoryIndex index.html
            #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            #AllowOverride None
            #Require all granted
    </Directory>
    # Static files in the examples webapp are served by Apache
    # Alias /examples /opt/tomcat/webapps/example
    # All requests go to ajp13_worker by default
    JkMount /* ajp13_worker
    # Serve this files using Apache
    JkUnMount /*.html ajp13_worker
    JkUnMount /*.jpg ajp13_worker
    JkUnMount /*.gif ajp13_worker
    JkUnMount /*.png ajp13_worker
    JkUnMount /*.svg ajp13_worker
    JkUnMount /*.js ajp13_worker
    JkUnMount /*.css ajp13_worker

    ServerAdmin info@example

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried changing persmisions of the index file, adding `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/example` with "`DirectoryIndex index.html`" but nothing works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it. Changed config file to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example
<Directory /var/www/example>
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        #AllowOverride None
        #Require all granted
</Directory>
# Static files in the examples webapp are served by Apache
Alias /example /opt/tomcat/webapps/example
# All requests go to ajp13_worker by default
JkMount /* ajp13_worker
# Serve this files using Apache
JkUnMount /example/*.html ajp13_worker
JkUnMount /example/*.jpg ajp13_worker
JkUnMount /example/*.gif ajp13_worker
JkUnMount /example/*.png ajp13_worker
JkUnMount /example/*.svg ajp13_worker
JkUnMount /example/*.js ajp13_worker
JkUnMount /example/*.css ajp13_worker

ServerAdmin info@example

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```